# Scale wpf Bar Chart manually

Tags: c#, wpf, scale, manual, bar-chart

I am scanning computers and their scale can not be like 1.5,2,2.5 they should be in whole numbers like 1,2,3,4.

my current code is

```
ICollection<KeyValuePair<String, int>> data = new Dictionary<String, int>();
            data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(Protocol, protocolCount));

            mycolseries = new ColumnSeries
                {
                    ItemsSource = data,
                    Title = Protocol,
                    IndependentValuePath = "Key",
                    DependentValuePath = "Value",                        
                };                
            mainChart.Series.Add(mycolseries);
```

if i change dependent value to "key" it gives strange errors like "new should be used with the invocation or element, or has not been initialized"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void Window1(){
       setChartSCale()
}


private void setChartScale()
{
    lamainChart.Interval = 1;
    lamainChart.Orientation = AxisOrientation.Y;
    lamainChart.ShowGridLines = true;
    //lamainChart.Maximum = 50;
        lamainChart.Minimum = 0;
}
```

call this method recursivly

```
private void addRecursiveLedgendAfterInit(string Protocol, int protocolCount)
{
      ICollection<KeyValuePair<String, int>> data = new Dictionary<String, int>();
      data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(Protocol, protocolCount));

      mycolseries = new ColumnSeries
      {
           ItemsSource = data,
           Title = Protocol,
           IndependentValuePath = "Key",                        
           DependentRangeAxis =lamainChart,
           DependentValuePath = "Value"
      };                
      mainChart.Series.Add(mycolseries); 
}
```